# Time Period of a periodic function

Tags: homework-and-exercises, frequency, oscillators

> Consider the following periodic function:
>   $$ f(t) = \sin(ωt) + \cos(2ωt) + \sin(4ωt) $$
>   What is the time period of the above periodic function?

The following is given in my book:

> Period is the least interval of time after which the function repeats. Here, $\sin(ωt)$ has a period $T_o = \frac{2π}{ω}$, $\cos(2ωt)$ has a period $\frac{T_o}{2}$ and $\sin(4ωt)$ has a period of $\frac{T_o}{4}$. The period of the first term is a multiple of the periods of the last two terms. Therefore, the smallest interval of time after which the sum of the three terms repeats is $T_o$, and thus, Time period is $T_o$.

I don't understand what the above lines mean.

Comment: Have you tried plotting these three functions, each on it's own? This would solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's first fix to some number. I'll choose $\omega=2\pi f$ with $f=1Hz$,  but you can choose any other number".

Now let's plot the three functions
[image: waves]

- After the time  $t = T_0 = \frac{2\pi}{\omega} =  \frac{1}{f} = 1s$ the blue  function $\sin{(\omega t)}$ has done a full oscillation. Thus, it has also done full oscillations after $t=\{2, 3, 4,  \ldots\}$.
- After the time  $t = T_0/2 = \frac{1}{2}s$ the red  function $\cos{(2\omega t)}$ has done a full oscillation. Thus, it has also done full oscillations after $t=\{1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, \ldots\}$.
- After the time $t = T_0/4 = \frac{1}{4}s$ the green  function $\cos{(2\omega t)}$ has done a full oscillation. Thus, it has also done full oscillations after $t=\{0.5, 0.75, 1, 1.25, \ldots\}$.

Thus, after $1s$ the blue curve has done one full oscillation, the red wave has done two and the green curve has done four full oscillations.